# Using one page to execute several actions

Tags: php

I'm in the middle of creating an admin panel however I'm wondering if its possible and how to do the following.

The admin panel will allow the user to complete three actions which are add, edit and delete (whilst communicating with the MySQL database). How can these actions only be completed within one file for example index.php?page=add, index.php?page=edit, index.php?page=delete?

So when the user wants to delete something only the delete part of the code is accessed in the file?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Your method would work, just make sure that the add, edit and delete actions are POST actions.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to be passing more info, for example a user id.

```
$userid = filter_var($_GET['userId'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);   

switch($_GET['page'])
{
    case 'add':
        // build mysql insert here using the userid.
        break;

    case 'edit':
        // build mysql update here using the userid.
        break;

    case 'delete':
        // build mysql delete here using the userid.
        break;

    default:
        echo 'unknown page action';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `$_GET['page']` you can get in PHP the value from URL associated to "page".

With $_POST, from data send via "post".
For some examples, see this tutorial: **[$_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST Variables](http://www.coursesweb.net/php-mysql/get-post-request)**.